# Increment value of a property inside mongodb document using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have this array of objects called "items":

[image: Array]

and for each object, I want to find the same object in mongodb using the "baseId" in the Base Document, and then update the "jumlahTerjual" amount by +1, this is the "Base Document":
[image]

I've tried this method but got an error called "jumlahTerjual is not defined":
[image]

How can I update it using findByIdAndUpdate correctly? Any answer will be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `jumlahTerjual` key exists for each object in you base document,
when you want to increment it (by any custom value), try:

```js
items.map(item => {
  return Base.findByIdAndUpdate(item.baseId, {$inc: { jumlahTerjual: 1 }}, function(error, counter) {
    if(error)
      return next(error);
    doc.testvalue = counter.seq;
    next();
  })
})
```

Use the `$inc` operator instead of `{ jumlahTerjual: jumlahTerjual + 1 }` as the update object. Because, currently the interpreter tries to find a local variable called `jumlahTerjual` which is being incremented by 1 and being assigned to the key in the object found by mongoose. Because we haven't defined a local variable for `jumlahTerjual` that is why you get the undefined error.

Because you only want to increment, instead of changing the value in the mongoDB record with a new value just use the `$inc` operator.

Comment: Yes, this answer is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you so much

Comment: @adityo-fauzaan Glad it solved your issue. If you would like to edit your question and add a more specific title like: "increment key value using findByIdAndUpdate in mongoose" or something along those lines. It would help many others with the same issue locate the question and answer better.